# WPF Storyboard flicker issue

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

With the code below, the control flickers whenever the image is changed for MouseOver/MousePressed? I am using Storyboard and Double animation.The image display for the button borderis very smooth with WPF Triggers but not with Storyboard. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a thread priority issue, try showing the window with ShowDialog() (modular window) instead of Show() and see if it still happens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your point. Can u please elobarate?
I am talking about the flickering when changing the background image for the button.

Comment: Playing a storyboard take CPU time, the UI thread must be available to do that. - Is it?

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other approach other than Storyboard in this case?

Comment: Your best bet, if you want a smooth animation, is to find a way to unburden the UI thread.

Comment: Instead of using a storyboard with times events, use a style with multitriggers. Also, if you can use vector graphics that change colors and not multiple images.

Comment: Multitriggers doesn't work for Silverlight!! I have to use images no colors.

Comment: You didn't write anywhere that it is a Silverlight issue and not WPF!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it. It's my mistake.

Comment: Try getting rid of the durations (timed events) - e.g. have mouseover change the image and normal change it back.